# Value of 1+1/2-2/3+1/4+1/5-2/6+.....

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

So recently me and my friends were solving a question which had the concepts of infinities come up. the question was this where we had to find $L$:
$$L = 1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{2}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{2}{9}+ \cdots $$
Now I simply added and subtracted the missing terms like $\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{6}, \cdots$ to the limit and then it became $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+ \cdots -  3 \left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}+ \cdots \right)$$
And so both of them cancel each other out and $L$ should be zero.
One of my friends justified this answer by telling that the cardinality of both sets are same, and hence this operation is justified.

But one more friend, came up with the argument that we can't  just subtract two summations both tending to infinity like that, and if done properly by taking individual summations then we will get the answer as $\ln(3)$ and not zero.
And indeed when I plotted this function on Desmos, the value did seem to go towards $\ln(3)$ instead of zero(at least for sufficiently large numbers like $x=100$)
[image]

So my question is, which of our approaches are right? And why is the other approach wrong? Because to me as a spectator both approaches and reasoning seemed logical.

Comment: the first reasoning has to be wrong. I don't how the two "cancel each other out"

Comment: Your proposed series operations only work when the series is absolutely convergent, which this one is not.  For conditionally convergent series, like this one, you can get any answer you want by reordering terms.  You have not included the demonstration that the sum is $\log 3$

Comment: @DS basically $3*1/3 = 1$ | $3*1/6 = 1/2$... and similarly for all terms, so the two summations become the same. So I thought we could cancel both of them out, as for each c in the first summation there exists a p in the second summation.

Comment: @mrtechtroid I did not understand your last comment. MathJax works in comments too.

Comment: @DS basically what I meant was that both of the summations become the same.... $1+1/2+1/3+.....$ and so I thought we could cancel them out.

Comment: See Ross Millikan's comment

Comment: A standard exercise on the effect of rearrangements like this is to show that
$$\frac11-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\frac17-\frac18+\cdots=\ln2,$$
but taking more of the positive terms earlier increases the sum to
$$\frac11+\frac13-\frac12+\frac15+\frac17-\frac14+\frac19+\frac1{11}-\frac16+\cdots=\frac32\ln2,$$
and, emphasizing the positive terms even more
$$\frac11+\frac13+\frac15+\frac17-\frac12+\frac19+\frac1{11}+\frac1{13}+\frac1{15}-\frac14+\cdots=2\ln2.$$ You are not allowed to rearrange infinitely many terms when, taken together, the positive/negative terms diverge.

Comment: that is, you cannot manipulate conditionally convergent series and divergent series as you wish

Comment: the error lies in the fact that you cannot "add and subtract" _undefined things_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument is invalid, since infinite sums are defined as the limit of the partial sums, so writing something like $1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + \dots - 3(1/3 + 1/6 + \dots )$ is sort of nonsensical since there are infinite terms before you reach the $-3$ if this is interpreted as a single infinite sum; if you want to interpret this as the difference of two infinite sums, $1 + 1/2 + \dots$ and $-3(1/3 + 1/6 + \dots)$ you cannot since both infinite sums diverge and the difference is meaningless.

In general, the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) tells you that your sum, since it is only conditionally convergent, can be permuted to converge to any value you like, so the first argument, which leans on permuting the order of the summands, does not give you the right answer. In essence, this boils down to the fact that alternating series, when conditionally divergent, have a subsequence that sums to $-\infty$ and to $+\infty$, so you can pick and choose to converge to whatever you like, and so for conditionally convergent series we cannot change the order of summation as easily.

To prove that the partial sums go to $\log(3)$ (the correct result) in a way that unifies your two perspectives, one possible way might be the following: recall that $\lim_{n \to \infty} -\log(n) + \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m} = \gamma$, the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Then, we have that if set $$a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{3n-2} + \frac{1}{3n-1} - \frac{2}{3n},$$ we have that $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ and that $$a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{3n-2} + \frac{1}{3n-1} + \frac{1}{3n} - \log(3n) - 3 \left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} + \dots + \frac{1}{3n}\right) + \log(3n)$$
and then rearrange to $$a_n = \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{3n} - \log(3n)\right) - \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{n} - \log(n)\right) + \log(3).$$
But now, by subtracting off $\log(3n)$ and $\log(n)$, the limits of the sequences in the parentheses exist (compare to before when without the logs the limits went to $\pm \infty$!) so we can legitimately write $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \gamma - \gamma + \log(3) = \log(3)$.

Comment: You can also add how such limit arguments fall for the OP's method